# Why can't I execute a script I created

Tags: command-line, root

I created a script and have `rwx` user permissions on it. It runs ok if I use the command `bash myscript` but when I try `./myscript` I get the result:

```
./: Is a directory
```

I also tried running it using `sudo` but get the same result.

Comment: If you provded the script, it would be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that you're leaving a space between `./` and `myscript`?

Comment: Right-click on the script, click on properties and post a screenshot of that window.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax You're right: http://askubuntu.com/revisions/696066/1

Comment: Just tested it and its indeed the case: http://hastebin.com/bakemoyefa.sm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't run

```
./myscript
```

as you say in your question, you have run

```
./ myscript
```

and you error message was

```
bash: ./: Is a directory
```

Note, the correct syntax is: *No* space character between the path `./` and the name of your script.

Answer (score -1):

You can create script with these steps :

```
sudo nano script_name.sh
```

Type some commands on it to execute later, and then make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x script_name.sh
```

And then you can run it by :

```
sudo ./script_name.sh
```

Comment: -1 why so many uses of `sudo`?

Comment: sorry, a bad habit of mine :D